# How to get exact updated column name in oracle trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm going to create a trigger to audit a table. Suppose my table define as below.

```
COUNTRY_ID   NOT NULL CHAR(2)      
COUNTRY_NAME          VARCHAR2(40) 
REGION_ID             NUMBER
```

and my log table created as below.

```
create table country_log(
  username varchar2(10),
  transaction_date date,
  new_value varchar(20),
  old_value varchar(20)
)
```

My half completed trigger would be like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_countryTable
AFTER UPDATE ON COUNTRIES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into country_log (username,transaction_date,new_value,old_value ) values (USER, sysdate,**:New, :Old** );
END;
/
```

I need to know instead of comparing each column value in :old and :new, how to get exactly updated column's new and old values.

Comment: What if multiple columns were updated? Do you want to log multiple rows for each column?

Comment: Suppose only one field is going to update on this table at a time.

Comment: By the way, the standard string datatype in Oracle is `varchar2`, not `varchar` or `char`.

Comment: What use is a log of changes that doesn't identify the row that was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `UPDATE` trigger, a column name can be specified with an `UPDATING` predicate to determine if the named column is being updated. Let's define a trigger as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_countryTable
AFTER UPDATE ON COUNTRIES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF UPDATING ('COUNTRY_NAME') THEN 
     -- :new.COUNTRY_NAME is new value
     -- :old.COUNTRY_NAME is old value
   END IF;

   IF UPDATING ('REGION_ID') THEN 
     -- :new.REGION_ID is new value
     -- :old.REGION_ID is old value
   END IF;

END;
/
```

[Oracle 11g triggers documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955)